# Change login screen after screen lock/suspend in mint 17

Tags: linux, linux-mint, login-screen

Is it possible, and i that case how, to change login screen after I have suspended my mint 17.
The problem is that after I have locked/suspended I get just black screen. To get the login manager i need to pres some key and then, if i do not type something it goes black again in ~10 seconds. It is XscreenSaver 5.15 that shows. Can I change it to something that looks better and is shown all the time?

Comment: I think the screen locker depends on which desktop environment you are using. Do you know which one you are using (KDE, Gnome, XFCE, etc.)?

Comment: I use Xfce4. Yes, it depends, but in linux it should be some configurations or alternatives that I haven't found jet.. I hope I do not have to switch DE just for that.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://xubuntu.org/news/screen-locking-in-xubuntu-14-04/). [Light-locker](https://github.com/the-cavalry/light-locker) might be the solution to your problems.

Comment: The article mentions that light-locker can only blank the screen and cannot display a screensaver. If you want full functionality and the ability to customize the lock screen, you may have to install/configure gnome-screensaver and its dependencies.